# Get the handle of a window that doesn't have a name

Tags: c#

I am using Findwindow() to get the IntPtr of a window name like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);



IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, WindowName);

if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
  RECT windowRectangle = GetWindowRect(handle);
}
```

This works when the windowname is not empty but how can i do it when the window doesn't have a name?

Comment: If it doesn't have a name, how do you want to identify it? Does it have some other property that you know?

Comment: Your only other choice is to walk the hierarchy. Be forewarned this is *extremely* fragile, window names and hierarchies are rarely documented, fixed properties. When they inevitably change, your spelunking-dependent application goes boom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Microsoft Spy++*, you can easily get advanced information on any window you have open. Open the utility, click *Find*, and locate the window you need to access programmatically by dragging the cursor [image] from the search box on to the required open window. The data will appear in the search window:

[image]

You can use the **Class:** field value to access the window that has no title:

To access the RStudio window by class name, I'd use

```
var handle = FindWindow("Qt5QWindowIcon", null);
if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
   // TO DO
}
```

Comment: Better hope that there aren't multiple windows of that same class. You'll only get the first one (not sure how the function determines "first", too lazy to look it up), and there's no way to enumerate the next ones.

Comment: I know, but it is just for a start. OP just asked how a window can be found if the window title is empty. One of possible ways is using the window class name.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1730013) originally posted by Jerry Fernholz in answer to a similar question:

```
    ...
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    ...

public class foo()
{
    ...

    [DllImport ("user32")]
    internal static extern int GetWindowText (int hWnd, String text, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport ("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowTextLength (int hWnd);

    [DllImport ("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow (String text, String class_name);

    [DllImport ("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindowEx (int parent, int start, String class_name);

    [DllImport ("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindow (int parent, uint cmd);

    public List<int> FindTitlelessWindows()
    {
        List<int> titleless = new List<int> ();

        Process [] procs = Process.GetProcesses ();
        IntPtr hWnd;

        foreach (Process proc in procs)
        {
            hWnd = proc.MainWindowHandle;
            if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                TraverseHierarchy (hWnd.ToInt32 (), 0, titleless);

            }
        }

        foreach (int i in titleless)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine (i);
        }

        return titleless;
    }

    public void TraverseHierarchy (int parent, int child, List<int> titleless)
    {
        String text = "";
        GetWindowText (parent, text, GetWindowTextLength (parent));
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (text))
        {
            titleless.Add (parent);
        }

        TraverseChildern (parent, titleless);
        TraversePeers (parent, child, titleless);

    }

    public void TraverseChildern(int handle, List<int> titleless)
    {
        // First traverse child windows
        const uint GW_CHILD = 0x05;
        int child = GetWindow (handle, GW_CHILD);
        if (0 != child)
        {
            TraverseHierarchy (child, 0, titleless);

        }
    }

    public void TraversePeers(int parent, int start, List<int> titleless)
    {
        // Next traverse peers
        int peer = FindWindowEx(parent, start, "");
        if (0 != peer)
        {
            TraverseHierarchy (parent, peer, titleless);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste code from [somewhere else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729505/get-handle-of-a-window-that-has-no-title-c), you **need to give credit to its original author**. And if it comes from another question on Stack Overflow, you should also flag this question as a duplicate of that other one.